# If Gridview Returns Now Rows Do X

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, if-statement

So I'm building an app that queries a database into a gridview (I'm using C# webforms) and one of the pages/queries I am using often returns no rows.  Is there a way to approach an if/else statement or a similar function if a SQL statement returns zero rows to a gridview?  My code is below.  Thanks guys.

```
da1.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
"SELECT FROM WHERE ORDER BY", cs1);
//  CREATE PARAMETERS FOR THE ABOVE SQL COMMAND
da1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custtno", visitno);

//  CLEAR AND FILL THE DATASOURCE FOR THE GRIDVIEW
ds1.Clear();
da1.Fill(ds1);

//  POPULATE THE PATIENT MEDS DATAGRID
GridView_custHx.DataSource = ds1;
GridView_custHx.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can do this:**

```
if(dataset.tables[0].rows.count!=0)
{
  bind your grid view here..
}
else
{
some other operation
}
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 2):

You've got your DataSet `ds1` right there, which you're then binding to the grid.

Assuming there's only one table in the DataSet:

```
if (ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    // no rows returned from the database, take some action
}
else
    GridView_custHx.DataSource = ds1;
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense and I put it in my code but now it's throwing an error "Cannot find table 0".  Does the "Tables[0]" need to be assigned a project specific value?

Answer (score 0):

Not really got enough information in your code to see what's going on. For example is 'ds1' a dataset, a datatable or something else? If it's a datatable then your not going to find a table at ds1.tables[0] as it's only 1 table.

Assuming it's a dataset then Avinash's code will work. If it's a datatable then simply change the check against the dataset to a datatable:

```
if(ds1.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    GridView_custHx.DataSource = ds1;
    GridView_custHx.DataBind();
}
else
{
    Do Something else...
}
```